# Using MAX within INNER JOIN - SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one called facebook_posts and the other called facebook_post_metrics.

facebook_posts looks like

```
NAME    id                      
a         1           
b         1            
c         4             
d         4
```

facebook_post_metrics looks like

```
number    FBID       Date_Executed             User_Executed
1         1        2012-09-18 16:10:44.917   admin
2         1        2012-09-25 11:39:01.000   jeff
3         4        2012-09-25 13:20:09.930   steve
4         4        2012-09-25 13:05:09.953   marsha
```

So the common column that would be used for the inner join is id from the facebook_posts table and FBID from the facebook_post_metrics.

So after the inner Join, the table should look like:

```
  name  number           FBID            Date_Executed             User_Executed
   a       1               1             2012-09-18 16:10:44.917   admin
   b       2               1             2012-09-25 11:39:01.000   jeff
   c       3               4             2012-09-25 13:20:09.930   steve
   d       4               4             2012-09-25 13:05:09.953   marsha
```

However, I want to include another condition while doing this inner join.
Basically, I just want to have the most updated entry for the joined table above.  I know I would use max(date_executed) and then group it by FBID. But I'm not sure which part of the SQL Query that would go into when using INNER JOIN. Please help me out.

Bottom line...I'd like to end up with a table looking like this:

```
  name  number           FBID            Date_Executed             User_Executed
   b       2               1             2012-09-25 11:39:01.000   jeff
   c       3               4             2012-09-25 13:20:09.930   steve
```

Comment: So, MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With a problem like this, I recommend breaking it down into pieces and putting it back together.

Finding the date of the most recent facebook_posts_metrics row is easy, like this:

```
SELECT fbid, MAX(date_executed) AS latestDate
FROM facebook_post_metrics
GROUP BY fbid;
```

So, to get the entire row, you want to join the original table with those results:

```
SELECT fpm.*
FROM facebook_post_metrics fpm
JOIN(
  SELECT fbid, MAX(date_executed) AS latestDate
  FROM facebook_post_metrics
  GROUP BY fbid) t ON t.fbid = fpm.fbid AND t.latestDate = fpm.date_executed;
```

Last, all you have to do is join that with facebook_posts table to get the name:

```
SELECT fp.name, fpm.number, fpm.fbid, fpm.date_executed, fpm.user_executed
FROM facebook_posts fp
JOIN(
  SELECT fpm.*
  FROM facebook_post_metrics fpm
  JOIN(
    SELECT fbid, MAX(date_executed) AS latestDate
    FROM facebook_post_metrics
    GROUP BY fbid) t ON t.fbid = fpm.fbid AND t.latestDate = fpm.date_executed
  ) fpm ON fpm.fbid = fp.id AND fpm.date_executed = fp.updated_at;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1485d/1) example.

**EDIT**

Based on your comments and looking over your design, I believe you can do something like this. First, get the latest `facebook_post_metrics` which I have described above. Then, get the latest `facebook_post` by using a similar method. This searches the most recent `updated_at` value of the facebook post. If you want to use a different date column, just change that:

```
SELECT fp.*
FROM facebook_posts fp
JOIN(
  SELECT id, MAX(updated_at) AS latestUpdate
  FROM facebook_posts
  GROUP BY id) t ON t.id = fp.id AND t.latestUpdate = fp.updated_at;
```

Last, you can join that query with the one for facebook_post_metrics on the condition that the `id` and `fbid` columns match:

```
SELECT fp.name, fpm.number, fpm.fbid, fpm.date_executed, fpm.user_executed
FROM(
  SELECT fp.*
  FROM facebook_posts fp
  JOIN(
    SELECT id, MAX(updated_at) AS latestUpdate
    FROM facebook_posts
    GROUP BY id) t ON t.id = fp.id AND t.latestUpdate = fp.updated_at) fp
JOIN(
  SELECT fpm.*
  FROM facebook_post_metrics fpm
  JOIN(
    SELECT fbid, MAX(date_executed) AS latestDate
    FROM facebook_post_metrics
    GROUP BY fbid) t ON t.fbid = fpm.fbid AND t.latestDate = fpm.date_executed) fpm
ON fp.id = fpm.fbid;
```

Here is an updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1485d/10) example.

Comment: Thank you! But, what if the facebook_post didn't have the "updated_at" column?

Comment: If it didn't, then how would you know which `name` to use? If I know that `fbid = 1` then I have no way of knowing whether to use `a` or `b`. @ShivamSachaphimukh

Comment: as long as the column "id" from facebook_posts and "FBID" from facebook_post_metrics are identical, would it matter?

Comment: @ShivamSachaphimukh That depends on your problem. If you don't care about 'a' or 'b', why bother to join that table in the first place?

Comment: okay, I guess over simplified my question a lot
So here's the link to what facebook_posts actually look like:
https://dataclips-next.heroku.com/qvwoghaoprqjwdsneiunaicdxjrd
Here's the link to what facebook_post_metrics actually look like:
https://dataclips-next.heroku.com/yjzrpjsfuobayoqfkkvwrqkldcji
Here's the link to the inner join:
https://dataclips-next.heroku.com/kjeprfqgrkvobijrhphrlgaadafr

So basically, I just wanted the most recent entry (i.e. the whole row) for each unique facebook_post_id

Comment: How would I sneak that condition within the INNER JOIN query?

Comment: @ShivamSachaphimukh in your linked things it appears that facebook_posts *does* have a time column, so why not join on that?

Comment: That's because the time column on facebook_posts isn't the most updated/most recent one.

Comment: So you want the most recent facebook_post joined with the most recent facebook_post_metrics?

Comment: yep, the main reason that I wanted to join the tables was because I wanted to include the name column.

Comment: @ShivamSachaphimukh I have updated the answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you need a `subquery` that calculated the `max` using `group by` and then join again with same tables to get all the details

As per the latest edit, the update_at column is no longer there in posts
as there are two entries, you can get only one by doing a group by

if you want all the entries then remove the aggregation and `group by` in the outer query.

```
select max(fp.name), fpm.number, fpm.FBID, fpm.date_executed,
       fpm.user_executed
from facebook_posts fp
join ( select max(Date_executed) dexecuted, FBID
       from facebook_post_metrics 
       group by FBID
      ) t
on fp.id = t.fbid
join facebook_post_metrics fpm
on fpm.fbid = t.fbid
and fpm.date_executed = t.dexecuted
group by fpm.number, fpm.FBID, fpm.date_executed,
       fpm.user_executed
```

Comment: Hey thanks!
sorry for the late edition...but would not having "updated_at" in the facebook_posts table change a lot?

Comment: @ShivamSachaphimukh, which row in face book post do you need if updated_at is not there

Comment: hey I kinda oversimplified my question.  this is more accurate:
okay, I guess over simplified my question a lot So here's the link to what facebook_posts actually look like: dataclips-next.heroku.com/qvwoghaoprqjwdsneiunaicdxjrd Here's the link to what facebook_post_metrics actually look like: dataclips-next.heroku.com/yjzrpjsfuobayoqfkkvwrqkldcji Here's the link to the inner join: dataclips-next.heroku.com/kjeprfqgrkvobijrhphrlgaadafr So basically, I just wanted the most recent entry (i.e. the whole row) for each unique facebook_post_id. How would I include that in the inner join query

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but you can do it by simply selecting the Max Date for the FBID in question. Something like this...

```
SELECT fb.name, fpm.number, fpm.FBID, fpm.date_executed, fpm.user_executed
FROM facebook_post_metrics fpm
    join facebook_posts fb ON fpm.fbid = fb.id AND fb.updated_at = fpm.date_executed
WHERE fpm.Date_Executed = (
SELECT MAX(f.Date_executed)
FROM facebook_post_metrics f
WHERE f.FBID = fpm.fbid)
```

Here a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1485d/15

Comment: this only brings up the most recent entry point without actually grouping it by FBID.
Thanks though, appreciate it.

Comment: That's strange, cause other than a couple of column names I got wrong, the output looks exactly like your expected output in your question. I've added a fiddle